# Enable Terminal beep with pactl

Tags: teminal-bell

I found a way to enable the terminal beep:

```
pactl upload-sample /usr/share/sounds/gnome/default/alerts/glass.ogg bell.ogg
```

But this gets lost after a reboot. How can I execute this command automaticaly, everytime I start the desktop?

Ubuntu: 11.10 with unity.

Comment: I also needed to run: `pactl load-module module-x11-bell display=:0.0 sample=bell.ogg` to make this work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to enable it for your user account every time you log in, you can add the line in the `Startup Applications`.

click on the gear icon in the upper right corner of the screen, in `Startup Applications` you can add a command to run every time you log in.

Answer (score 1):

#### No Terminal Bell

*From:* [Fix missing keyboard bell in terminal on Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/228096/terminal-bell-doesnt-ring)

"To fix this problem persistently:

Run **gconf-editor** and if the `desktop | gnome | peripherals | keyboard | bell_mode` setting is present then change it from **off** to **on**

Add `pactl upload-sample /usr/share/sounds/gnome/default/alerts/glass.ogg bell.ogg` to the file **~/.xprofile**

Add `[ "$DISPLAY" ] && xset b 100` to the file **~/.bashrc**
The simplest way to activate this solution is to reboot.

#### Adjust the Volume of the Terminal Bell

*From:* [Pulseaudio - X11 Bell Events - ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio#X11_Bell_Events)

I found that Pulse Audio had no volume control for the terminal bell.

To adjust the volume of the X11 bell, run the following command:

```
xset b 100
```

Where **100** in the command is a percentage. So to set 50% volume you would run `xset b 50` This requires the **xorg-xset** package.

I changed the line in **~/.bashrc** to:

```
[ "$DISPLAY" ] && xset b 50
```

to bring the volume to a "normal" level but allowing me to raise it for special alerts after a command ends.

To implement this solution immediately for a terminal window that is already open, run the pactl command and run the xset command in the terminal window in question."

```
pactl upload-sample /usr/share/sounds/gnome/default/alerts/glass.ogg bell.ogg
xset b 100
```

#### Changing the bell sound

I did not like the glass.ogg file that they used so I created a new sound file using [sox](http://linux.die.net/man/1/playwith):

```
sox -n bell.ogg synth 0.1 sine 300-3000 vol 0.005
```

in my home directory. I then changed the command in **~/.xprofile** to:

```
pactl upload-sample ~/bell.ogg bell.ogg
```

to change the sound go to the home directory and run a sox command (like the one above) to create a new **bell.ogg** file. Then in the terminal to use the new sound run the:

```
pactl upload-sample ~/bell.ogg bell.ogg
```

command.

#### Alias beep and beep-vol

I also created two aliases (both in bash and fish)
**beep** and **beep-vol**.

**beep** can be used in scripts or to alert you when a task is finished

**beep-vol** can be used to set the terminal bell volume on the command line without remembering the xset b command. Just type `beep-vol 50` to set the volume to 50%.

#### bash

You can add these to your **~/.bashrc** or if you have a working **~/.bash_aliases** file you can add them there.

```
alias beep="echo -ne '\007'"
alias beep-vol="xset b $1"
```

#### fish

You can save these as files in your **~/.config/fish/functions/** folder:

**~/.config/fish/functions/beep.fish**

```
function beep
        echo -ne '\007';
end
```

**~/.config/fish/functions/beep-vol.fish**

```
function beep-vol
        xset b $argv;
end
```